# Появлется отступ на странице справо

Tags: css3, html5

При уменьшение окна браузера появляется вот такое пространство(смотреть изображение).
В адаптивной вёрстке разбираюсь плохо.
Думал проблема в марджинах или паддингах, но нет.
Очень надеюсь на решение этой проблемы с Вашей помощью.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код проекта по ссылке: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qbrDE9VtdSEDTOjN_s4U3PEJJI8OqdYP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

У вас у `<li>` в `<div class="navigation">` стоят боковые отступы по 60 пикселей. Конечно, будет не помещаться.

Можете убрать их совсем, а в `<div class="navigation">` добавить, например это:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap: 10px;
```